# How to achieve page turn in the <nav> class when making a web crawler?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the sales and categories of the top products on https://shopee.co.id/top_products. But I got stuck on how to automates every page on the navigation bar. Particularly there is an expanded list, and I can't figure out how to go into that just by looking at the html code. Here's the picture of the web, and some of my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36',
    'cookie': '_gcl_au=1.1.961206468.1594951946; _med=refer; _fbp=fb.2.1594951949275.1940955365; SPC_IA=-1; SPC_F=y1evilme0ImdfEmNWEc08bul3d8toc33; REC_T_ID=fab983c8-c7d2-11ea-a977-ccbbfe23657a; SPC_SI=uv1y64sfvhx3w6dir503ixw89ve2ixt4; _gid=GA1.3.413262278.1594951963; SPC_U=286107140; SPC_EC=GwoQmu7TiknULYXKODlEi5vEgjawyqNcpIWQjoxjQEW2yJ3H/jsB1Pw9iCgGRGYFfAkT/Ej00ruDcf7DHjg4eNGWbCG+0uXcKb7bqLDcn+A2hEl1XMtj1FCCIES7k17xoVdYW1tGg0qaXnSz0/Uf3iaEIIk7Q9rqsnT+COWVg8Y=; csrftoken=5MdKKnZH5boQXpaAza1kOVLRFBjx1eij; welcomePkgShown=true; _ga=GA1.1.1693450966.1594951955; _dc_gtm_UA-61904553-8=1; REC_MD_30_2002454304=1595153616; _ga_SW6D8G0HXK=GS1.1.1595152099.14.1.1595153019.0; REC_MD_41_1000044=1595153318_0_50_0_49; SPC_R_T_ID="Am9bCo3cc3Jno2mV5RDkLJIVsbIWEDTC6ezJknXdVVRfxlQRoGDcya57fIQsioFKZWhP8/9PAGhldR0L/efzcrKONe62GAzvsztkZHfAl0I="; SPC_T_IV="IETR5YkWloW3OcKf80c6RQ=="; SPC_R_T_IV="IETR5YkWloW3OcKf80c6RQ=="; SPC_T_ID="Am9bCo3cc3Jno2mV5RDkLJIVsbIWEDTC6ezJknXdVVRfxlQRoGDcya57fIQsioFKZWhP8/9PAGhldR0L/efzcrKONe62GAzvsztkZHfAl0I="'
}
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
shopee_url = 'https://shopee.co.id/top_products'

driver.get(shopee_url)
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
response = driver.page_source
driver.close()
soup = bs(response, "html.parser")

url_list = []

for tags in soup.find_all('li', attrs={'class': 'stardust-tabs-header__tab stardust-tabs-header__tab--active'}):
    for a tag in tags.find_all('a',):
        url_list.append()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]Look at the network tab, there are several calls made there for example this:
https://shopee.co.id/api/v4/recommend/recommend?bundle=top_sold_product_microsite&limit=20&offset=0
that will give you all the nav bar links in a nicely formatted json.

Sometimes you can get more information by looking at the different requests being made on the network tab than by parsing the html body[image]

If you look at the first item in the nav bar it says Kuota Data Internet, if you click on it, you're redirected to https://shopee.co.id/top_products?catId=ID_V2L0_65

that means each url in the nav bar is of the form https://shopee.co.id/top_products?catId=CAT_ID

[image]
you can find CAT_ID for each one looking at https://shopee.co.id/api/v4/recommend/recommend?bundle=top_sold_product_microsite&limit=20&offset=0
and maybe changing the limit to something other that 20 and the offset to something different than 0

for Kuota Data Internet the CAT_ID. is ID_V2L0_65
as shown here:
[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't find where the links are at. Could you help me with that? Much thanks!

Comment: 1. Open the console, so you can see the network tab
2. Go to https://shopee.co.id/top_products
3. under the "name" column, you'll see the different requests that have been made, click on the one that starts with `recommend?bundle=top...`, click on headers on the right part (the image I uploaded shows the preview tab, which has the data. If you click on headers you'll see the url)

Comment: I understand this. What puzzles me is where the links to different tabs of the navigation bar are at.